# Phrase search with slop in Lucene

Tags: search, lucene

I am having trouble understanding how this can be a hit.

In my index I have:

wa wb wc wd

And my search term is:

"wd wc wb wa"~6

How can the second query be rearranged into the first with only 6 re-arrangements? My initial assumption was that this needed slop 8 minimum to be a hit (move wa 3 positions left, move wd 3 positions right, move wc 1 position right, move wb 1 position left), but I actually get a hit with slop 6 or more.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The edit distance also contains the delete and insert operations. In your case following 6 operations can be made to achieve the resulting match:

- Move wb right
- Move wb right
- Delete wc
- Delete wd
- Insert wc
- Insert wd

Comment: Isn't this confusing proximity search (with quotes) with fuzzy search (without quotes)?

Comment: the proximity search always requires also the insert after a delete, fuzzy search doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

In https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html#getSlop--, the edit distance between "quick fox" and "the fox is quick" would be at an edit distance of 3 seems to be inaccurate.

It is not said that the edit distance used by Lucene is the Levenshtein distance (insertion, deletion, substitution, all of weight 1) but a test of "quick fox" PhraseQuery with a slop of 2 (it's enough) hits the text "the fox is quick" (1 deletion + 1 insertion).